# Replace matching elements within two arrays with a different value using for loops and if conditions in python 3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, loops

I have two arrays:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
b = np.array([8,2,5,0])
```

I would like to replace the elements of a with -3 if the same elements appear in b. I would like to do this with a for loop with/without an if condition. Here's what I have:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == b[i]:
       a[i] == -3

        
              
print(a)
```

And I get this error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-5f8874f38b74> in <module>()
      7 
      8 for i in range(len(a)):
----> 9     if a[i] == b[i]:
     10        a[i] == -3
     11 

IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4
```

From my understanding it's a size discrepancy. Is there a way to solve my issue with arrays of different sizes?

Comment: does it have to be numpy arrays? not lists?

Comment: If `i=4` what should `b[i]` return? Assuming, `secondArray` is `b`, that is. [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) is a great tool for these kind of questions.

Comment: The `in` operator allows to check if an element is in a list.

Comment: You really should not use numpy here if you are going to do it this way. In numpy, you'd do `a[np.in1d(a,b)] = -3` Just use lists if you aren't actually going to use numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work for a python `list`. This is not a numpy based solution

```
a=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b=[8,2,5,0]
common=set(a).intersection(b) # {8, 0, 2, 5}
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] in common:
        a[i]=-3
print(a) # [-3, 1, -3, 3, 4, -3, 6, 7, -3, 9]
```

Comment: Works with `np.array` as well.

Comment: ohh, I was not aware, not a numpy user, but I assume numpy has functions to avoid looping generally

Answer (score 2):

You are using the indices from `a` to access elements from `b`, which is much shorter. You quickly overshoot the  length of `b` and encounter an error. Recommend you try the following:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
b = np.array([8,2,5,0])

for i,v in enumerate(a):
    if v in b:
        a[i] = -3
       
print(a)
```

Out:

```
[-3  1 -3  3  4 -3  6  7 -3  9]
```

Explaining this behavior in depth might take a bit more space than I want to fill here *but* there's a pretty good [tutorial here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm) that can help you wrap your head around using `lists`s in Python.

Comment: Thank you James this worked! I will check the tutorial for further understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Others have pointed out that the real issue is that you can't check membership by looping over both arrays at the same time. Using Python's `in` operator is a good alternative.

However, if we're in Numpy, we can use the Numpy element-wise version of the same thing:

```
a[np.isin(a, b)] = -3
```

`np.isin(a,b)` returns a boolean ndarray indicating whether each element of a was in b, which we can use to index a and only set the values that were in b to -3.